# Merge two arrays by grouping based on elements of 1st array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays (arr1 & arr2) like this

```
var arr1 = ["A","B","C"];

var arr2 = [["A","aa"], ["A","ab"], ["A","ac"],["B","ba"],["B","bb"],["B","bc"],["C","ca"],["C","cb"]];
```

I want to group them together into 3rd array in javascript based on the values of first array. Desired Output:

```
arr3 = [ ["A",["aa","ab","ac"]], ["B",["ba","bb","bc"] ], ["C",["ca","cb"]] ]
```

NOTE: I had arr2 to begin with and was able to retrieve first value and remove duplicates into arr1.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
var arr1 = ["A", "B", "C"];

var arr2 = [
  ["A", "aa"],
  ["A", "ab"],
  ["A", "ac"],
  ["B", "ba"],
  ["B", "bb"],
  ["B", "bc"],
  ["C", "ca"],
  ["C", "cb"]
];
var newVal = arr1.map(function(x) {
  var filter = arr2.filter(function(y) {
    return y[0] == x;
  }).map(function(y) {
    return y[1];
  });
  return [x, filter];
})
console.log(newVal);
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/mhdr76ns/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

> NOTE: I had arr2 to begin with and was able to retrieve first value and remove duplicates into arr1.

Rather than creating `arr1` as a middle step, I would probably create an object as the middle step:

```
var obj = arr2.reduce(function(a,b){
  if (!a[b[0]]) a[b[0]] = [];
  a[b[0]].push(b[1]);
  return a;
},{});

// obj is now {"A":["aa","ab","ac"],"B":["ba","bb","bc"],"C":["ca","cb"]}
```

To convert that object to your desired output array:

```
var arr3 = Object.keys(obj).map(function(v) { return [v, obj[v]]; });
// [["A",["aa","ab","ac"]],["B",["ba","bb","bc"]],["C",["ca","cb"]]]
```

If you actually need the `arr1` array for something else then:

```
var arr1 = Object.keys(obj);
// ["A", "B", "C"]
```

But notice that `obj` is quite useful for further processing, because if you need to get the values associated with `"B"` you don't need to search through an array again, you can simply say `obj["B"]` (which will give the array `["ba","bb","bc"]`). So the second `"B"` value is `obj["B"][1]`.

Further reading:

- [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map)
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)